# local variable 'context_dict' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django-views

Can someone please explain me what this error means? What is assignment? Where context_dict should be? Or I made some other mistake? I am new to Django. Thank you so much.

```
def add_page(request, category_name_slug):
    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        cat = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit=False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                # probably better to use a redirect here.
                return category(request, category_name_slug)
           else:
               print form.errors
        else:
            form = PageForm()

        context_dict = {'form':form, 'category': cat}

    return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)
```

I got this error:

```
local variable 'context_dict' referenced before assignment
```

and exception is pointing me on line with return render(reqyest, 'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)

the same Traceback

Comment: If the request method is not `'POST'` you don't define `context_dict` but you try to use it in the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that in Python indentation is important. The problem is that your variable `context_dict` has no reference outside of the if statement because of how it is indented. So declare your variable `context_dict` outside the if statement as so:

```
    context_dict = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
    <rest of code here>
```

Answer (score 1):

I re factored my code again and this way works. My context_dict is now outside the if outer statement and else: form = PageForm() is in outer if statement now not as before in inner if statement. Thank you guys for helping me out.

```
def add_page(request, category_name_slug):
    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        cat = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit=False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                # probably better to use a redirect here.
                return category(request, category_name_slug)
            else:
                print form.errors
    else:
        form = PageForm()

    context_dict = {'category': cat, 'form': form}

    return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to only reply to POST requests.

```
def add_page(request, category_name_slug):
    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        cat = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit=False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                # probably better to use a redirect here.
                return category(request, category_name_slug)
           else:
               print form.errors
        else:
            form = PageForm()

        context_dict = {'form':form, 'category': cat}
        # indented - only reply to post requests
        return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)
    # if this is not a post request, raise an exception (handle your way later..)
    raise Exception('NOT A POST REQUEST')
```

Comment: this way i got error: NOT A POST REQUEST but I actually declared variable context_dict outside the if statement and it works :)

Comment: The error was intentional. You need to decide how you handle this, and remove the error in case it's not an error.